# Why does this user still have an account?

Tags: support

I flagged this comment from an OP: 'Hey you Nigga @Quentin ...I'm new here...Watch your words!!!', but only the comment got deleted.

Not only is this user rude and abusive, he is absolutely determined to get his code fixed without any  effort himself.

Such users should be banned immediately and the question deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057078/is-anything-wrong-with-my-code-help-plz

Comment: *"only the comment got deleted"* - what were you expecting? Unless this was a *pattern* of abusive behaviour, I wouldn't expect a single comment to get the user banned or deleted. That's a crap question, no doubt, but hardly grounds for such a response; it's attracted some well-deserved downvotes and will shortly be closed, deleted and (hopefully!) forgotten about. If the OP has deleted questions of a similar standard, they may well be auto-banned shortly anyway.

Comment: From what I can see, Q mentioned the brainfuck language.  OP then makes the comment you cited.  I don't think OP is a native speaker, so he might not know how rude that comment can make him seem.  Hell, he might have learned a decent amount of slang listing to rap.  Yo nigga this, and yo nigga that, etc.  Not saying that additional deleted content may shed more light on this, but a simple warning may very well be enough in this case.

Comment: That comment might have drawn enough flags to be deleted automatically without a moderator's intervention. It's also possible that a moderator elected to just send the user a warning.

Comment: It wasn't the 'Nigga' comment alone.  The OP also edited the question and so invalidated Sourav's fixes, (quentin reversed it).  The OP made no attempt to debug.  The OP continually posted code updates in comments.  The OP refused the advice to apply Sourav's fixes, test, debug and then repost if still had problems.  The whole mess was one continual 'FIX MY CODE FOR ME WHILE I MAKE NO EFFORT' tirade that was unworthy of the effort that Sourav put in to help.  I was utterly disgusted and embarrassed by it all.

Comment: Yes, the OP's behaviour is not appropriate for SO. However, neither does it justify account deletion. And, frankly, it was clear from the first revision that it was going to be an unproductive experience to engage!

Comment: @MartinJames Well, the video I've linked, certainly doesn't fall in the category of [Be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback).

Comment: @MartinJames, that was your first time. You'll get used to it.

Comment: OK, looks like I've been defeated on this one:)  At least I cannot be blamed now if that user drains anyone else.

Comment: @MartinJames the post is deleted, perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: Google's cached version - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SvgWTxTzlcoJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/31057078/is-anything-wrong-with-my-code-help-plz+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

Answer (score 76):

I handled your flag, removed that comment, and had a very pointed conversation with the user behind it. Obviously, racist slurs have no place in civil society.

I didn't delete the user, because I saw no indication that this was an account of a troll or other repeat abuser of the site. We don't delete accounts or "ban" people because they asked a single poorly-received question, nor because they insulted another in a comment. We only delete accounts when it is clear that those accounts are being used to circumvent site policies or to obviously post spam or trolling.

The insults stopped with that one comment (which appeared to be due to them mistaking the mention of the language "Brainfuck" for an insult against them), and as I said we've had a conversation about this. Beyond that, if you have a problem with the quality of the question, vote on it how you will. I'm not deleting someone's account because of a single bad question.

I always like to believe in redemption for people, and choose to warn people about problematic behavior first to give them a chance to reform. This doesn't always work, but I've seen many people learn from initial troubles and go on to be great members of the site. I want to give them that chance.

Comment: OK, I concede defeat, though 'SO' and 'civil society' don't really seem to belong in the same conversation sometimes:)

Comment: To be entirely fair, it's fairly easy to think that somebody talking about Brainfuck (the language) is insulting you or your code if you don't know what the language is, which many people don't.

Comment: @gobernador: I certainly wouldn't introduce it into a question/answer without being **very** careful to say that that was the name of the language.

Answer (score 8):

Users that were flagged being rude, abusive or not helpful/constructive won't be banned/deleted immediately.

There's several steps to be taken IIRC

1. They'll get a warning moderator message asking to improve their behavior
2. They'll get banned for a certain time if not improving, and having been flagged again
3. Even before, they might get question banned (because the engine decides)
4. If there's more frequent flagging, and no hope seen by the mods (several agreed), for the account to improve, the account may be deleted

Well, I'm not a mod actually, but I think that's how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot kill the user for making 1 mistake. You should educate him instead. The deletion of the comment probably sent the message that rudeness is not acceptable here; the user will probably not do it again.

Also, kill the user because he doesn't know what *debugging* is? I say better educate him instead. If he doesn't want to learn - ignore him (or do whatever other negative thing you want). But you cannot assume the worst about him (judging by what? His name?) right from the beginning - assume the best instead.

Comment: I agree that the user shouldn't be deleted immediately but I think the point was more about the "rude and abusive" part. Though, probably also partially due to seeming like a lost cause and not even trying to help himself.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't the abusive comment directed at quentin that bothered me so much as the OP's 'tude toward Sourav's fixes.  He was plainly intent on bleeding S. dry of blood in an attempt to get his code fixed with minimal effort on OP's part.

Comment: @MartinJames All of that is reason to downvote the post.  None of that is grounds for deletion of the account.

Comment: @MartinJames: And of course, if the user continues to behave that way (with or without abusive comments), their account will indeed be suspended (lots of poor questions have that effect). If that doesn't work, they'll be barred.